How to get direct link download from google driver
i have i fileID image in google driver
i know can use for download use webContentLink
https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=?id={fileID}
https://drive.google.com/uc?id={fileID}&export=download
but i want from domain like this
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/iJLrRbmCGxKzgK1Hx7W70KeFUJ38FZ81xjvMQz8TF92AWIfeMTkKS9jNX_HT8gmSTerjMB0JqCvpPVGlwLCbA1fW2SWqECN7XjSvDKWlTZsJ0-JNkuVoT_GQW_M7EOS9GnChr28uNhK7PdMh=d
the way get link download ll3.googleusercontent.com from fileID google driver.
